# Method on class [com.secure.Role] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm completing doing everything same as described in tutorial at Grail website . However I'm receiving this strange error message :

> Method on class [com.secure.Role] was used outside of a Grails application

I've done it in my business computer and personal notebook. I've tried to it with Spring IDE and different grails versions. What's the problem can not understand.

Comment: Add the implementation where `Role` is referred and also the link to tutorial mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hard to know for sure without the offending code...but the only time I've run into this message is in a unit test when I forget to include a domain object in    @Mock() and try to use its gorm methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run a unit test without first applying mocking to a domain class then you will get this error.

Also integration tests cannot curerntly be run in an IDE and require use of the command line (some IDEs integrate the command line to run these tests). If you run an integration test from the IDE you will likely get an error like this.